# Почему hasKey не видит поле в ответе?

Tags: java, test-automation, rest-assured

Имеется тест:

```
@Test
    public void sixTest() {
        FlowerList flowerList = new FlowerList();
        Specification.installSpec(Specification.requestSpec(), Specification.responseSpec());
        Response response = given()
                .when()
                .get("/api/unknown")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .body("data.year", hasKey("2001"))
                .extract().response().as((Type) FlowerList.class);
```

Мне нужно проверить, чтобы по крайней мере в одном поле year содержалось значение 2001. Но я получаю исключение:

```
Expected: map containing ["2001,"->ANYTHING]
  Actual: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
```

Что я делаю не так? Теоретически husKey должен возвращать одно значение - 2001

get:

```
{
    page: 1,
    per_page: 6,
    total: 12,
    total_pages: 2,
    data: [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "cerulean",
    year: 2000,
    color: "#98B2D1",
    pantone_value: "15-4020"
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "fuchsia rose",
    year: 2001,
    color: "#C74375",
    pantone_value: "17-2031"
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasKey` проверяет наличие поля/ключа с заданным значением.
В данном случае следует использовать [`hasItems`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/RestAssured.html):

```
// ...
    .body("data.year", hasItems("2000", "2001"))
```